# MySQL cluster: I could not create any new table

Tags: mysql

I have just `mysql-cluster-gpl-7.1.4b-win32` installed on my XP computer.

There are three command:

1. `START ndb_mgmd -f d:\work\my_cluster\conf\config.ini --initial`
2. `START ndbd --defaults-file=d:\work\my_cluster\conf\my.cnf --initial`
3. `START mysqld --defaults-file=d:\work\my_cluster\conf\my.cnf --user=root --console`

I notice in step `3.`, I have log continually pop up:

```
[Note] NDB: Creating mysql.ndb_schema
```

Then I open another command window, I type mysql -u root

I could create database test, but I could not create table. It says query is ok, 0 rows are effected.

But when I say, use test, show tables. I could not see any table is created.

Any reason and suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is found. The reason is that there is type error in configuration file.